# I want to run django and php site on one ip and port?

Tags: php, django, apache, mod-wsgi

My local IP is `192.168.29.248`. And I want to run the PHP site normally when I run 192.168.29.248:8086 and Django website as `192.168.29.248:8086/django/`. How can I achieve this?
My current `vhosts.conf` is:

```
<VirtualHost *:8086>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help?

Comment: Are you already running a WSGI server (like uWSGI or Gunicorn) on this server?

Comment: Yes i'm running mod_wsgi